# Vue jest unit testing, can't test or render component from components library

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, components

We have some complex forms and depending on the login we render different buttons.

However the  component comes from a library installed via NPM. So I'm having trouble reaching them in Jest.

Is there a way to render / load the components so I can test the right ones are present?

```
describe('P1 buttons - show the correct buttons for credential type and registration status', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await wrapperBeforeEach();
  });
  test('expect button for OPEN_BANKING_UK_MANUAL to be visible', async () => {
    currentRegistrationDetails.credentials = institutionP1UkAutoBarclays;
    wrapper.vm.currentRegistrationDetails.platform = 'P1';
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    // wont work if Button is component
    const button = wrapper.find('[data-test-id="button-p1-download-ssa"]');

    // this would work if the Button component was local to the project
    const buttomExternal = wrapper.findComponent(Button);

    const registrationP1 = wrapper.find('.registration-p1');
    console.log(registrationP1.html());

    // this fails as Button doesn't render at all.
    expect(buttomExternal.isVisible()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

The HTML from `console.log(registrationP1.html());` is this —

```
  <div class="form-actions mb-5">
    <div class="form-actions-content">
      <!----> 
      <!---->
    </div>
  </div>
```

The buttons should appear between the

```
      <!----> 
      <!---->
```

We keep running into these issues with our applications whilst using our component library.

The actual button markup is

```
        <Button
          data-test-id="button-p1-download-ssa"
          type="primary"
          class="primary button"
          :is-loading="savingSsa"
          :on-click="downloadTheSsaFromModal"
          >Request the SSA</Button
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only have to test that the props are bound correctly with the `npm` dependency. It's not in your scope to test that the `Button` from an other library is working.

Comment: hey - I need to test that the right button is being shown. There are around 5 each displayed under certain v-if conditions. The parent div is being displayed but the Button component don't seem to be visible / reachable by jest.